# Flutter web-rendrer html is not showing network images in release mode on mobile chrome and firefox

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-debug, canvaskit

I'm new in Flutter and I have build my portfolio dynamic and responsive web app where I have picked image URLs from Firebase. The images are not shown before by using NetworkImage widget. Then I tried using `flutter run -d chrome` and images are shown properly as expected.

Then I used "html rendrer" properly in 'index.html' it works fine in debug mode:

```html
<script>
    window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>
```

It keeps giving me this note in debug mode each time on hot restart:

> window.flutterWebRenderer is now deprecated. Use
> engineInitializer.initializeEngine(config) instead. See:
> https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/initialization

Once my portfolio completed, I used this to build release of my app from [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers):

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
```

I have used GitHub pages to host it.

[Link](https://msaadsaleem1001.github.io)

Now the problem is that it is running as expected only on my Chrome browser, but on others, like Firefox, mobile Chrome and Vivo browser, it is not loading images as I have not used the html rendrer.

[It is the example of firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV8jC.png)

Expected output:
[My chrome browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UunWH.png)

Comment: yes this is an ongoing issue of CORS. Workaround is use HTML renderer or even better download images and render as bytes. Read more about issue at https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/web-images

Comment: As for the renderer error, the window instance is deprecated so you need to use engineInitializer. The code is in the pointed url in warning message.